# What does upside down "v" ($\wedge$) mean in this equation?

Tags: notation, signal-processing

I have a simple question, but it is hard to google it. I have this equation here:

$$y(t, x) = \sum_{i=1}^{d}(|x_i| \wedge t)^{2}
$$

Here $x$ is a size $d$ signal and $t$ is just a scalar. I am not sure how to read that equation in english... I understand everything except for how they use the $\wedge$ here...

If context helps, this is part of a cost function, based on a threshold $t$ that is selected, for your vector $x$.

Comment: It probably means the minimum of $|x_i|$ and $t$.

Comment: @user1551 Are you sure about that? If it helps, "t" is supposed to signify a threshold value, and $x(i)$ is just some sample from a d-length vector.

Comment: Of course I am *not* sure, because I don't see why one would want to take the minimum of a spatial quantity ($|x_i|$) and a temporal quantity ($t$). Yet the wedge symbol usually has three meanings: logical conjunction, some sort of "wedge product" and the minimum function. As both $|x_i|$ and $t$ are scalars, we can rule out the first two possibilities. So the minimum function is the most plausible explanation I can think of.

Comment: @user1551 I didnt mean for my comment to come off as rude, far from it. I only meant to ask for further insight. The $t$ btw is not a temporal quantity, it is just a threshold. (I edited the question). Based on what you are saying, this means "take the sum of squares of whatever is minimum between x(i) and t" correct?

Comment: Yes, I mean $(|x_i|\wedge t)\equiv\min(|x_i|,t)$.

Comment: Interpreting the symbol as "minimum" would seem to be consistent with interpreting $t$ as a threshhold. Although there are other possibilities. It could mean, "zero, unless $|x_i|\ge t$, in which case, $|x_i|$." But surely the equation didn't drop into your lap from the sky. Surely there is some context to help you work it out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it would seem to mean minimum after all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$|x_i|\wedge t$ probably means $\min(|x_i|,t)$.

There are three usual meanings of the wedge ($\wedge$) symbol: logical conjunction, some sort of "wedge product" and the minimum function. As both $|x_i|$ and $t$ are scalars, we can rule out the first two possibilities. So the minimum function is the most plausible interpretation I can think of. But certainly, you should look at the context of your equation to make sure that this is a correct interpretation.