# What's the meaning of $\mathbb{N}_0,\wedge$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What's the meaning of the $\wedge$ in $\mathbb{N}_0,\wedge$?

The context is an exercise about the properties of mathematical operations.

I'm aware of $\wedge$ as a logic operator, but I'm quite sure that's not meant here.

I've found lots and lots of pages about a $\wedge$- or external product on vectorspaces, but I don't think I should interpret $\mathbb{N}_0$ as a vectorspace?

I've also found $a\wedge b = \min(a,b)$ (in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286367/what-does-upside-down-v-wedge-mean-in-this-equation)).  That would make sense to me.  Is there a logical explanation why this should the correct interpretation?

Comment: As I know $\mathbb N_0$ is the set of natural number with $0$.

Comment: The logical explanation is that it just depends on the context. If you gave some context maybe someone could verify this for you.

Comment: $\wedge$ is often used for the infimum operation on lattices (partially ordered sets such that every two-element subset has a supremum and an infimum). For a totally ordered set, that becomes $\min$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane, I guess you mean *without* 0?  (Or at least that's the common meaning in my country)

Comment: @longtom That would be a nice confusion. Where I come from, $\mathbb{N}_0$ is used to emphasise that the set contains $0$, since some people don't include $0$ among the natural numbers.

Comment: @par.  There hardly is a context.  The exact exercise is to consider the magma $\mathbb{N}_0,\wedge$ and to find out what properties the operation has.

Comment: @longtom For the french notation we denote $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ but I saw this notation $\mathbb N_0=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ here.

Comment: Usually, when working on integers, $\wedge$ is the greatest common divisor

Comment: @DanielFischer, I guess we found a not-so-universal part of the mathematical language...

Comment: @arbautjc Wow, I've never seen that yet.

Comment: @longtom One doesn't need to look hard for that.

Comment: @arbautjc, the previous lecturer teaching that course said that, too, but I'm not able to contact here anymore...  (alas)

Comment: It is probably not the gcd if $0 \in \mathbb{N}_0$

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, when I say "usually", it's probably exagerated :-) But it's the notation I learned in university (first year). In France, in case that matters (and for notation, that *often* matters)

Comment: @arbautjc "locally usually" ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer I agree with arbautjc we use this  notation and also PGCD for $\gcd$

Comment: I can confirm that $\mathbb{N}_0$ is meant to be $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.  So gcd would be the most common interpretation?

Comment: @DanielFischer The nice thing is it's compatible with the partial order notation: gcd is the "min", and lcm the "max". The notation is confirmed on the *french* wiki: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_grand_commun_diviseur#Notations

Comment: @arbautjc I never doubted its use. I just hadn't come across it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol $\wedge$ is borrowed from the theory of [lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28order%29#Lattices_as_algebraic_structures).  Normally there is also $\vee$.  They are called meet and join, respectively.  They are each binary, infix, operations, that satisfy certain lattice axioms.  Two familiar lattices on $\mathbb{N}$ are:

1. $\wedge$ denotes gcd (greatest common divisor), while $\vee$ denotes lcm (least common multiple).
2. $\wedge$ denotes min, while $\vee$ denotes max.

Absent any context it is impossible to tell which lattice on $\mathbb{N}$ is being discussed.  If $\mathbb{N}_0$ includes  $0$, we must exclude the first possibility; but in either case there are many possible lattices.

Comment: So the question, without context, is ambiguous?

Comment: In Belgium $\mathbb{N}_0$ means $0$ is excluded.  That might suggest the first possibility is meant?

Comment: I would say the question is ambiguous, since there are many possible lattices on $\mathbb{N}_0$.  For example, one could take the non-standard total order $0<2<4<6<\cdots<1<3<5<\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

In some programming languages, $\wedge$ means the bitwise xor function.  That is, $a\wedge b$ means computing the sum of $a$ and $b$ in base two without carry: so $2^k \wedge 2^k = 0$, $2^k \wedge 2^l = 2^k + 2^l$ if $k \ne l$, and $\wedge$ is commutative and associative.