# Meaning of $\lor$ and $\land$

Tags: logic, correlation

What is the meaning of $\lor$ and $\land$ in the following function:$$\phi(x):= (x\land1)\lor(-1)$$
To give a little context, this should be a bounded transformation to bound a correlation estimator to $-1$ and $1$. I know of their use in logic but I've never seen them used like this.

Comment: these should be max and min (I’ve often seen those notation in stats : $x∧y$ is $min(x,y)$), so the result is to bound the expression to 1 and -1 as you said

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610760/42969:  “$\wedge$ denotes min, while $\vee$ denotes max.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you represent false and true as $0$ and $1$ respectively, $x\land y=\min\{x,\,y\}$ while $x\lor y=\max\{x,\,y\}$ (verify these with a truth table if you like). This $\land=\min,\,\lor=\max$ identification is the basis of [semilattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice). Using it on real numbers is just a very boring example of a lattice (i.e. a semilattice with both, satisfying [absorption laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_law)).