# What does this operator used in the definition of the elliptical potential lemma mean?

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking at lemma 19.4 in the free online edition of Bandit Algorithms by Lattimore and Szepesvari, which the authors say is called the elliptical potential lemma. The definition and proof of the lemma makes use of an operator which I have never seen used in this way (I am familiar with its uses in propositional logic). It is the upside-down V, as indicated in the image linked below. Can someone explain the meaning of the operator in this context?

[Link to screenshot from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLDW.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286367/42969

Comment: On page 5, it references ∨ and ∧ as being "maximum and minimum, a ∨ b = max(a,b) and a ∧ b = min(a,b)".

Comment: Hi, Jeremy, when we post a question, it is better to be self-contained and complete, and others can easily understand and give answers and feedbacks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe this is the wedge product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra

Comment: @Anonymous73648 is definitely correct